# Torque on output axle

Tags: forces, torque

After a lot of brainstorming, We haven't quite been able to figure out the relation between torque and direction in the picture below:

[image]

We have two connecting rods between a wheel and an axle (B). These are are hinged in the point C.
Rotating the wheel 180 degrees by axle A either CW or CCW, how are the forces transferred through the rods and what is the resulting torque on axle B? Trying to figure if it's the better option going CW or CCW.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is  your effort at solving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the diagram leaves a lot to be desired, I think I understand the mechanism. It is a classic 4 bar linkage really.

[image: fig1]

In terms of quasi-static response we can assume member *CD* is a two force member with equal and opposite forces at *C* and *D*. So using the moment arms $a=\| A A' \|$ and $b = \|B B'\|$ one can write the tension of *CD* as

$$ F_{\rm CD} = \frac{\tau_A}{a} = \frac{\tau_B}{b} $$

and that is the relationship between torque at A and torque at B.

Another way to approach this problem is to do a kinematic study to find the relationship between the rotation at *A* and the rotation at *B*. Thus due to conservation of energy (power in = power out) you will have

$$ \tau_A \omega_A = \tau_B \omega_B $$

My favorite method for doing kinematics is with the graphical method. Here we find all rotation centers of the linkages and the radial distance from the rotation center to a pin is like the radius of gear. So the gear ratio between two parts is found from the radii to their rotation centers.

[image: fig2]

Going from the known rotation $\omega_A$ at *A*, and the radius $r_{AD}$ we find the velocity of *D*

$$ v_D = \omega_A r_{AD} $$

Next from the radii between the rotation center *G* of the link *CD* and the end points we have

$$ \omega_G = \frac{v_D}{r_{DG}} = \frac{v_C}{r_{CG}} $$ which is solved for $v_C$.

Finally the rotation at *B* is

$$\omega_B = \frac{v_C}{r_{BC}} $$

All together we have

$$ \tau_B = \left( \frac{r_{BC} r_{DG}}{r_{AD} r_{GC}} \right) \tau_A $$

Comment: Wow, thank You for the elaborate response, and looking up 4 bar linkage, it seems to be exactly that. We were searching google for anything that might relate to the problem, but never saw the 4 bar linkage. Guess You also need to know exactly to look for that.

I acknowledge the shortcomings of the of diagram, and previous comments. But with 15 years since my last physics class, it proved quite the challenge to put what I had in my head onto a virtual piece of paper, for someone else to understand. Let alone finding a tool to draw it.

Comment: BTW - I used PowerPoint to make the diagrams.

Comment: Was just hoping, that someone would still be capable of connecting the dots despite of the gaps in explanation and diagram. Thank You.

As a sidenote, what is the tool You used to draw Your diagram?

Comment: Nice, would never have guessed powerpoint...

Comment: I have [**`IguanaTex`**](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) installed that allows me to add $\LaTeX$ math expressions to my slides.